# CCMenuItemFont color change

Tags: objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

How can I set the color of a CCMenuItemFont. I've been searching for hours, returning 0 valid results. They're all outdated.

```
[CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Futura"]; 
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:40];
    CCMenuItem *Play = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Play" target:self selector:@selector(goToLevelSelect:)]; 

    CCMenu *menuPlay = [CCMenu menuWithItems: Play, nil]; 
    menuPlay.position = ccp(50,100);
    [menuPlay alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:10];
    [self addChild:menuPlay];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CCMenuItemFont](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_menu_item_font.html) is derived from [CCMenuItemLabel](http://learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_menu_item_label.html) which has a label property:

```
CCMenuItemLabel *play = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Play" 
                         target:self selector:@selector(goToLevelSelect:)];
play.color = ccRED;
```

Comment: ERROR: Request for member 'color' in something not a structure or union.