# CCMenuItemFont can not change color, always white

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem

I tried below two methods to change the color of CCMenuItemFont,but does not work. It's always white.

```
CCMenuItemFont *gameItem=[CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Game" target:self selector:@selector(goToPlay:)];
[gameItem setColor:ccGRAY];
```

or

```
gameItem.color=ccGRAY;
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Shouldnt it look like this CCMenuItemLabel *play = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Play" 
                         target:self selector:@selector(goToLevelSelect:)];
play.color = ccRED;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303291/ccmenuitemfont-color-change

Answer (score 1):

`CCMenuItemFont` is a subclass of `CCMenuItemLabel`. We should actually set the color of the `CCLabelTTF` which is added as a child on `CCMenuItemFont` or `CCMenuItemLabel`. We can actually change item color like this

```
CCMenuItemFont *gameItem=[CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Game" target:self selector:@selector(goToPlay:)];
////[gameItem setColor:ccGRAY];     //No effect.
gameItem.label.color = ccGRAY;      //Eureka. Color changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to a CCMenuItemLabel:

```
CCMenuItemLabel *gameItem = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Play" 
                     target:self selector:@selector(goToPlay:)];
gameItem.color=ccGRAY;
```

Comment: initFromString is deprecated, You have to use initWithString for initialization.

Comment: I did the same thing. But the color is still white not grey!!!